# checkbox should be checked when clicked on Button which is not working on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox with and text and link to accept the terms and conditions when terms and conditions are accepted then checkbox automatically should checked out and below code is working fine in all browsers expect safari in mac and iphone safari.

Could you please help me how to resolve this issue for safari

```
$("#accept-button, #decline-button").on("click", function (event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($(event.target).attr("id") == "accept-button") $("#access_agreement").addClass("accepted").find("#agreement-accepted").prop("checked", true).change();
  else if ($(event.target).attr("id") == "decline-button") $("#access_agreement").removeClass("accepted").find("#agreement-accepted").prop("checked", false).change();
  $("#access-agreement__overlay").removeClass("overlay__show").addClass("overlay__hide");
  $("#access_agreement a").focus();
});

 <div class="checkboxes__item" id="access_agreement">
        <input tabindex="-1" class="input checkboxes__input" name="agreement-accepted" id="agreement-accepted" type="checkbox"<%= agreementAccepted ? " checked" : "" %> value="1" />
        <label class="checkboxes__label" for="agreement-accepted">
          <fmt:message key="access_agreement" />
        </label>
        <div id="access-agreement__overlay" class="overlay overlay__hide">
          <div id="access-agreement__header" class="overlay__header" tabindex="0"><img id="help__<%= inputName %>__close-icon" class="icon icon__close" src="design-icon-close.png" tabindex="0" /> <fmt:message key="access_agreement.header" /></div>
          <div id="access-agreement__body" class="overlay__body" tabindex="0"><fmt:message key="access_agreement.body" /></div>
          <div class="row overlay__buttons">
            <div class="column">
              <button class="button button--secondary" id="decline-button"><fmt:message key="access_agreement.decline" /></button>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <button class="button button--primary" id="accept-button"><fmt:message key="access_agreement.accept" /></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNDgS.png)